# How can one configure the name a docker-compose service will have in dockerd dns (to remove underscores)?

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose

I have a service called `my_service` which is resolvable by other containers on shared networks using the same name as the service definition: `my_service`. I'm not a fan of underscores in hostnames or domainnames as they are not widely accepted/supported.

I would like to change the name in the dockerd dns so that it is reachable via "my-service" instead, hopefully without changing the service name in the compose file.

```
version: "2"
services:
  my_service:
    image: foo
    hostname: my-service
  networks:
    - "default"
    - "othernet"
...
networks:
  othernet:
    driver: bridge
```

I've tried the compose setting `hostname: my-service`, which gets added to the `Config.Hostname` key on the container. But the key doesn't get used for name resolution from other containers.

*Additionally, and this is a side issue, but compose consistently mangles names for all sorts of different reasons (to satisfy linux network bridge names, container names, network names, volume names etc) I don't immediately see why removing underscores from dns names would be considered one step too far.*

Answer (score 0):

[Network aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#aliases) are one way to do it. You would provide, for each network you wish to change the container's name on, a list of alternate names for it.

So, your service definition would become:

```
services:
  my_service:
    image: foo
    hostname: my-service
    ...
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
           - my-service
           - my-srv
      othernet:
        aliases:
           - my-service

# the global `networks` section at the bottom doesn't need to be touched.
...
```

**Note1:** You don't have to add aliases on each of the networks the container is on. Omit the aliases key for that section if you don't need any additional names.

**Note2:** The aliases section will *add* new names, but it won't remove any existing default mappings. So the container would *also* still be reachable under `my_service` after you add more `aliases`.

If you do `docker inspect <containerid>`, you would be able to see other aliases for the container on each network. By default, dockerd will throw in the short form of the containerid, e.g. `afe2314`, in the bag of aliases.